# Dashboard data with Good data SDK

Tags: javascript, dashboard, gooddata

I need to consume my company 'Target Social R3 V3' dashboard data with Good data Javascript SDK. First I'm trying to get pinterest data as start but I'm receiving **error 400 Bad request**. I'm newbie to good data api and following methods given in good data examples in Java script SDK.

```
$('#root').append('<div class="login-loader">Logging in...</div>');

gooddata.user.login(user, passwd).then(function() {
// Loged in
$('div.login-loader').remove();
$('#root').append('<div class="loading">Logged in... Loading metrics</div>');

// Do your stuff here
// ...
gooddata.md.getMetrics(projectId).then(function(dataSets) {
    $('div.loading').remove();
    $('#root').append('<div class="dataLoading">Laoding data...</div>');

    $('#root').append('<p>Total number of metrics ' + dataSets.length + '</p>');
    elements=[];
         dataSets.forEach(function(ds) {

        var dstr = JSON.stringify(ds.title);
        if(dstr.toLowerCase().indexOf("pinterest account followers") > 0)
        {
            var did = JSON.stringify(ds.identifier);
            $('#datasets').append('<li>'+did+'</li>');
            elements.push(did);
        }

    });
    $('#root').append('<p>Total number of choosen metrics '+elements.length +  ' and element '+elements[0] +'</p>');

    gooddata.execution.getData(projectId, elements).then(function(dataResult)
    {
        $('div.dataLoading').remove();
        console.log('Social Data:\n'+ JSON.stringify(dataResult));
    });

});
});
```

I'd appreciate if some one could explain about attributes and metrics passed here as parameters.

Comment: By Pinterest data you mean you are downloading a data from dataset in GoodData that contains Pinterest data? Have you specified elements for computing report (metrics and attributes)?

Comment: Yes you are right, but basically my goal is to extract complete dashboard data from gooddata dataset. Later I figured out that I should be rather using `getObjectDetails` method then `getData` method. with dashboard uri. But still I'm figuring out how to pass attributes and metrics. Sorry if I'm too much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sample is under gooddata-js/examples/ folder (let's assume is named 'mysample') and it has `index.html` file in that directory. Set `user` and `passwd` variables in your script file to your real GoodData user name and password. Run `grunt dev` and access your sample at `https://localhost:8443/mysample/index.html`. It should work.

If it does not work, please provide the details (message body) of the 400 error you are getting.

Comment: I'm exactly doing steps you defined above but I'm clue less how to use correct attributes and metrics to get my dashboard data. However I moved little ahead by using `getObjectDetails` method rather then using `getData` method which now returns me dashboard DOM in json.